# How to call javascript function on document.ReadyState inside updatepanel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, webforms

I can not call javascript function asynchronosly inside UpdatePanel1 when document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').readyState !== "complete". When Button1 fires it works asynchoronosly on server side but does not work on client side and so it does not call javascript function.

Here is my UpdatePanel1:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode ="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers= "true" runat="server" >
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonLoadGridView" /> 
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button_test2" />   
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button_test3" />               
     </Triggers>                
  <ContentTemplate>`
```

My Button: ID="ButtonLoadGridView":

```
protected void ButtonLoadGridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = "dsData";
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Here is javascript code need to call when GridView1 is ready:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () 

    {
            if (document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').readyState !== "complete") 
        
        {
     
            window.onload = function ti() 

        {     

        
                document.getElementById('<%= Label_Clients.ClientID %>').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
                alert("Your data is loaded');

        }
     }
  }
```

What I expect is that this simple  javascript code from above:

```
 document.getElementById('<%= Label_Clients.ClientID %>').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
                alert("Your data is loaded');
```

be called after when GridView1 is ready but it does not work asynchoronosly in UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0):

First up, you probably don't need those triggers to be defined (but, let's deal with one issue at a time here).

So, so we have 3 use cases:

Run some js after web page loads (common).

Run some js after a update panel runs its cycle.

Run some js after a button click in a update panel - ONLY if the button is clicked.

The trick is to inject the script to the page, but you inject to the UPDATE panel, and NOT the page.

This will show how this works:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <div style="padding: 35px">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="button in UPdate panel"
                    OnClick="Button1_Click" />

                <br />

                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="button in UP <br/>- run js after click"
                    OnClick="Button2_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>

</form>
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // runs after page is ready
            $.toast({
                heading: "Page ready event",
                text: 'Run after page load',
                position: 'mid-center',
                icon: 'info',
                hideAfter: 5000,
                allowToastClose: false,
                loader: false,
                showHideTransition: 'slide'
            });

        })

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(myupdatepanelend);


        function myupdatepanelend() {
            // runs after page is ready
            $.toast({
                heading: "After update panel event",
                text: 'Run after update panel',
                position: 'mid-center',
                icon: 'info',
                hideAfter: 5000,
                allowToastClose: false,
                loader: false,
                showHideTransition: 'slide'
            });

        }

        function RunAfterUpbutton() {
            // runs after button click in UP
            $.toast({
                heading: "After update panel button click",
                text: 'I Run after btn click in update panel',
                position: 'mid-center',
                icon: 'info',
                hideAfter: 5000,
                allowToastClose: false,
                loader: false,
                showHideTransition: 'slide'
            });
        }


    </script>
```

So, when we launch this page, then page load/ready will fire/run.

If we click on the first button in the UP, then the after Update panel event will run.

If we click on the 2nd button in the UP, then we inject a script to run, and thus both after UP panel code will run (looks like you don't need this part), and ALSO our button click injected js code will run.

code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("update panel button run");

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // run some code, and THEN trigger some js code to run client 
        // side

        Debug.Print("button 2 click in up panel");

        string sJava = "RunAfterUpbutton()";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, 
            UpdatePanel1.GetType(), 
            "aftertest",sJava, true);

    }
```

The results look like this:

[image]

So, you can on button click (inside the update panel), run code behind, and THEN also trigger some client-side js code to run by injecting the js script you want to run (RegisterStartupScript).

So, in most cases, the RegisterStartupScript is against the page, but as above shows, you can do this against the Update Panel.

Comment: I have used RegisterStartupScript but function scrollIntoView() does not work only alert function...

Comment: Tthe above is a demo and proof of concept on how to have js code run as a result of a button click in a UP. So, perhaps scrollinfoView is running, but not working correctly. On the other hand, perhaps you try using Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true; As it stands now, I have the above working run js code after button click in a update panel - so, I have to build a working example to further persue this, since NOW your problem is not the js code running, since as I pointed out the above shows your js code routine should run.  I can try this with a working gv, but it the js code runs.

Comment: I just tested the above UP with a grid view, and I am able to freely re-bind (re-load) the GV without any issues or special code to re-set the scroll position. This suggests to me that you do NOT need some js code to make this work, and WORSE yet, I'm betting that your suffering a full page post-back. Put a 2 second delay in your button click - do you see a "browser spinner" while this code runs? (you should not). I am able to re-load and re-bind my gridview, and the current scroll position does not change.